# SQL query to show repeating data from child records in columns

Tags: sql-server-2000, pivot, duplicate-data

I have the following tables in a SQL Server 2000 database:

**Master**

```
MasterID | Details   | [other fields]
=====================================
PK (int) | Free text | ...
```

**LogTable**

```
LogID    | MasterID | UserID    | LogDate    | LogText
==========================================================
PK (int) | FK (int) | VarChar(2)| Date stamp | Free text
```

There may be many Log entries for each master record.

I have a query which extracts the most recent three associated Log entries for each Master row as shown below. Note that appropriate conversion and formatting is performed to achieve the `LogData` concatenation (omitted for clarity):

```
SELECT 
    M.MasterID, M.Details, L.LogDate + L.UserID + L.LogText AS LogData 
FROM
    MasterTable M 
INNER JOIN 
    LogTable L ON M.MasterID = L.MasterID 
    AND L.LogID IN (SELECT TOP 3 LogID FROM LogTable 
                    WHERE MasterID = M. MasterID ORDER BY LogDate DESC)
```

This produces output like this:

```
MasterID | Details | LogData
========================================================
1        | First   | 05/11/2012 AB Called Client  
2        | Second  | 08/11/2012 CD Client Visit  
2        | Second  | 07/11/2012 CD Called Client  
2        | Second  | 05/11/2012 AB Called Client
```

What I need to achieve is showing the data from the second table as columns in the output, all reported against each single master record, thus avoiding repeated data. Like so:

```
MasterID | Details | LogData1                    | LogData2                    | LogData3
===========================================================================================================
1        | First   | 05/11/2012 AB Called Client | (null)                      | (null)  
2        | Second  | 08/11/2012 CD Client Visit  | 07/11/2012 CD Called Client | 05/11/2012 AB Called Client
```

Note that in the real world requirement, this solution will be part of flattening 5 tables with the output consisting of approx 20,000 rows and 90 columns of data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Thanks Marc. It looks much better as a result.

Comment: @JonWilmer what you are trying to do is a `PIVOT` but SQL Server 2000 does not have a `PIVOT` function so you will need to look at other options including `CASE` with aggregates or cursor based.

Comment: The answer below works in theory. Actual requirement is to flatten data from 5 tables. Output will consist 25,000 records of 90 columns of data. Cursor based solution will take much too long to execute. Any suggestions as to a practical solution to the problem?

Comment: @JonWilmer Unfortunately your best solution would be to upgrade from sql server 2000, then you could take advantage of additional tools which would make this type of operation much easier.

Comment: Or just make the client use the fine UI that we built for him!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to post this, just to show it can be done, but HIGHLY SUGGEST, not do it through SQL.   Should be done through the UI that's displaying to be more dynamic on your columns.   Even then, I would design this differently.

```
-- create master table
DECLARE @MasterTable TABLE (
    [MasterID] [int] IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL ,
    [Details] [varchar] (50) ,
    [AdditionalField_1] [varchar] (50) ,
    [AdditionalField_n] [varchar] (50) 
)
-- create log table
DECLARE @LogTable TABLE (
    [LogID] [int] IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL ,
    [MasterID] [int] NULL ,
    [UserID] [varchar] (2) ,
    [LogDate] [datetime] NULL ,
    [LogText] [varchar] (50) 
) 
-- insert into master table
INSERT INTO @MasterTable  (Details)
        VALUES ('First')
INSERT INTO @MasterTable  (Details)
        VALUES ('Second') 
-- insert into log table
INSERT INTO @LogTable  (MasterID, UserID, LogDate, LogText)
        VALUES (1, 'AB', '05/11/2012', 'Called Client')   
INSERT INTO @LogTable  (MasterID, UserID, LogDate, LogText)
        VALUES (2, 'AB', '05/11/2012', 'Called Client')   
INSERT INTO @LogTable  (MasterID, UserID, LogDate, LogText)
        VALUES (2, 'CD', '07/11/2012', 'Called Client')   
INSERT INTO @LogTable  (MasterID, UserID, LogDate, LogText)
        VALUES (2, 'CD', '08/11/2012', 'Client Visit') 
-- create table to display data
DECLARE @MyTemp TABLE (MasterID INT, Details VARCHAR(50), LogData1 VARCHAR(50), LogData2 VARCHAR(50), LogData3 VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @MyTemp SELECT MasterID, Details, NULL, NULL, NULL FROM @MasterTable
-- create vars
DECLARE @ID INT, @NewID INT, @MasterID INT, @NewValue VARCHAR(100)
SET @ID = 0
-- loop through data
WHILE @ID >-1
BEGIN
    -- clear vars
    SELECT @NewID = NULL, @MasterID = NULL, @NewValue = NULL
    -- get first record
    SELECT TOP 1    
        @NewValue = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), LogDate, 103)+ ' ' + UserID + ': ' + LogText
    ,   @MasterID=MasterID
    ,   @NewID=LogID 
    FROM @LogTable WHERE LogID>@ID
    -- if no data, exit loop
    IF @NewID IS NULL
        BREAK
    -- update record based on valuds in fields
    UPDATE m 
        SET @ID = @NewID
        ,   LogData1 = (CASE WHEN m.LogData1 IS NULL THEN @NewValue ELSE m.LogData1 END)
        ,   LogData2 = (CASE WHEN m.LogData1 IS NOT NULL THEN 
                            (CASE WHEN m.LogData2 IS NULL THEN @NewValue ELSE m.LogData2 END)
                        ELSE m.LogData2 END)
        ,   LogData3 = (CASE WHEN m.LogData1 IS NOT NULL THEN 
                            (CASE WHEN m.LogData2 IS NOT NULL THEN 
                                (CASE WHEN m.LogData3 IS NULL THEN @NewValue ELSE m.LogData3 END)
                             ELSE m.LogData3 END)
                        ELSE m.LogData3 END)
    FROM @MyTemp m
    WHERE m.MasterID=@MasterID
END
--display all data
SELECT * FROM @MyTemp
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: It sounded like you just wanted to join two tables to give one result set, but since that may not be the case I need more from you.  

To help better understand what your trying to do, create an example script that creates two temp tables, runs the select that gives that result that you currently get. Then under it, put what results your wanting to get based on the data in these temp tables. It will help me better understand your problem.

Comment: @marc_s I can't seem to post code after hitting edit in the above answer.   I hit Cntl-K, it says paste code here, I do, then it tells me it's not formated as code.   It's copied and pasted directly from SQL Management Studio and it's fully formated nicely, not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Jon, I understand what is being shown.  There nothing I can't do in T-SQL as I've worked in it since SQL 6, if I can just better understand the requirements I can help.

Comment: Hi Chizl, I have added the script to original post.  
Desired output is as shown originally.

Comment: So your wanting the rows from one table to be columns for this select? That can be done if it's a fixed set of rows, like 2 or 3, but because they are rows, what if they have 50? Are you looking for 50 columns to show up?   BTW, this isn't something people usually do within SQL, it's done at the UI that is displaying it.   It can be done in SQL, but its going to be ugly...

Comment: Just so you know, this will consists of a loop and it's seriously fround apon by any DBA.   If you have a UI that is display it, this can be pulled as an array and build the columns in a very clean manner.

Comment: As I said in the OP, there may be many Log rows for each Master record. However, the query I have already written only retrieves the first three as required. Therefore, there will only be a maximum 3 rows returned from the Log table.  
I was hoping there would be a way to pivot the data from the second table?

Comment: Pivot tables aren't available until SQL2005. I edit my answer above for what will work in SQL2000. Let me know if that will work for you.

Comment: This gives loads of errors. I'm trying to run it in Query Analyzer. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are the errors, I'm able to run it just fine, however I don't have SQL2000 at the moment, so its possible I'm doing something that it doesn't like.   Been a while since I used SQL2000.

Comment: I just noticed you have simi-colons in your's which I copied to mine.  I can't be sure, but I don't think SQL2000 likes those.

Comment: I've updated it..  Maybe it doesn't like the AS TABLE..    Based on this, http://odetocode.com/articles/365.aspx, SQL2000 can use table varibles.

Comment: This works in theory. Actual requirement is to flatten data from 5 tables. Output will consist 25,000 records of 90 columns of data. Cursor based solution will take much too long to execute. Any suggestions as to a practical solution to the problem?

Comment: Upgrade SQL and use PIVOT tables?  :P  I remember having to do this kind of thing back in the day and yes, Cursors are really bad, which is why I used a loop.   Not the most efficient solution, but better than cursors.

Comment: You know the most practical solution for SQL2000 is to do it within the application that is displaying it, not SQL, if that's possible.

Comment: Please update your question with the comments that clarify it.  Also, please update the answer with any clarification that came about.  I'll be back through to purge the comments after, since they are of little use to a googler (and a bad user experience to read through).

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Thanks, I understand this requires some cleaning up.

Comment: @Chizl Thanks for your input. This works, although not a practical solution as discussed. Marking this as accepted answer.